# How does find prevent endless loops (e.g. when renaming files while finding them)?

Tags: linux, bash, find

Please consider the following command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec mv '{}' '{}_foo' \;
```

How does `find` prevent endless loops in this case?

On one hand, I believe to know that find does *not* work like shell globs do, i.e. it does not fetch a list of all `*.jpg` files, stores that list internally and then processes the *list entries*. Instead, it gets the files to process "incrementally" from the underlying O/S and processes each of them as soon as it knows about it (let's ignore a certain amount of buffering which might take place since this is irrelevant to the question). After all, as far as I have understood, this is the main advantage of `find` over globs in directories which have a lot of files in them.

If this is true, I would like to understand how find prevents endless loops. In the example above, `1.jpg` would be renamed to `1.jpg_foo`. From discussions on StackOverflow and elsewhere, I know that renaming might result in the file (name) occupying a different slot in the directory file list, so chances are that find encounters that file a second time, renames it again (to `1.jpg_foo_foo`), and so on.

Obviously, this does not happen.

Comment: In your example, the renamed file wouldn't be covered by the match since it would end in `_foo`.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice this had the [tag:bash] tag. But this does look like the same question, just yell at me if you disagree...

Comment: @ilkkachu No, you are right. Despite searching thoroughly and for a long time, I did not find the other question. So your action is appropriate. The bash tag is here because I hoped to attract people who know both variants (i.e. `find` as well as globs) and could confirm that and tell me why `find` is faster by orders of magnitudes in some cases.

Comment: @Binarus, oh, hmm, I didn't realize you meant find vs globs as such an important point. That might be worth a question in itself, if it isn't here already. I think there's a couple of other points than just speed: standardization and batching come to mind.

Comment: @Binarus, also, technically that older question doesn't answer the possibility of infinite loops, which I suppose are they're theoretically possible in practice, but unlikely. Though with simple implementations of  `find` and `readdir`, and an OS that always made new files appear at the end of the list, there could even be a deterministic infinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within a single directory, it may be as simple as reading the entire filelist before processing it (and `strace` makes it looks like that's what happens):

```
# keep reading entries first
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
getdents(4, /* 1024 entries */, 32768)  = 32752
getdents(4, /* 1024 entries */, 32768)  = 32768
getdents(4, /* 426 entries */, 32768)   = 13632
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
```

(output abridged for readability)

```
# process stuff later
clone(...
wait4(...
--- SIGCHLD...
clone(...
wait4(...
--- SIGCHLD ...
```

In general, though, `find` does not prevent any loops at all. If you move files to a subdir, that happens multiple times:

```
mkdir -p sub/sub/sub/sub
find -type f -exec mv {} sub/{}_foo \;
```

This results in `sub/sub/sub/sub/file_foo_foo_foo_foo` and such things. (`-depth` might help in this case).

It's best to avoid any possible clashes in the first place instead of blindly relying on `find` employing some magic that just isn't there. Your question before your edit was a good solution, since it simply didn't match the already renamed file at all.

Even in cases where not strictly required, it's nice to make it clear that files can't and shouldn't be processed twice. We're renaming `jpg` files here and not `foo` files.

Also even if `find` in a single call will prevent processing files twice, there's always a risk the script as a whole will re-run and find will run a 2nd time, so you'll need safeguards in place either way.

Comment: Thank you very much and +1. Notably, the part of your answer with the recursive folder structure was very enlightening. In addition, I still think that `find` in general is not guaranteed to read the entire file list from a directory before processing the files, even though this was the case in your test. So I think I have learned that lesson: Just carefully craft renaming, moving, copying and the search pattern so that `find` won't treat the same file twice.